# JsonSerializable not working correcly

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have a class with several date parameters(Java.util.Date objects). I have annotated them using JsonSerialize as follows.

```
@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
public Date getRepReceivedDate() {
    return repReceivedDate;
}

@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
public void setRepReceivedDate(Date repReceivedDate) {
    this.repReceivedDate = repReceivedDate;
}

@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
public Date getRepPostedDate() {
    return repPostedDate;
}
```

I have JsonDateSerializer class as follows.

```
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>{

private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");

@Override
public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    gen.writeString(formattedDate);
}
```

}

Now I have few doubts by the way.

1. When I call getter on the particular attribute, does serializer suppose to serialize it and convert data into the specific format. When I call getter what I get is 2014-10-12 like dates.( MMM should print Nov ) instead of 10 I think
2. I use ObjectMapper to create the JSON string afterwards. like follows,

   ```
   String jsonString ="";
   try {
       PaymentEntry paymentEntry = paymentEntryService.getPaymentEntry(chequeId);
       ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       jsonString = objMapper.writeValueAsString(paymentEntry);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

In the jsonString I get some dates like 2014-Jan-02 and some like 2014-04-22.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Uhm, why don't you use this annotation on the field itself?

Comment: Hi @fge
I followed this(http://loianegroner.com/2010/09/how-to-serialize-java-util-date-with-jackson-json-processor-spring-3-0/) article. It says use with getter.

Comment: Well, it does work on fields, so try it ;)

Comment: Well it doesn't work on field @fge. But I could get it working. my be a cache issue was the problem. Anyway still I appreciate a explanation from someone on how this work.

Comment: What version of Jackson is that? I _have_ made it to work on instance fields using Jackson 2.2.x

Comment: upgrading the jackson-mapper-asl version to 1.9.13 worked for me.